# How do I force a div element to extend to the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, height

I have been playing with CSS *height* property for a while, but I still can't find a solution.

This is my CSS:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px; 
    min-height:100%;
}
#container{
    position: relative;
    padding:40px;
    margin-top:2%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    margin-bottom:2%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this using CSS or may I use a javascript function?

Comment: change your height: 100% to height: auto

Comment: Try height 100% on the html, body, and container.

Comment: Look at sticky footer: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: Set as `position: absolute; height: 100%`. It will fit the window height;

Comment: Perhaps this question & my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399396/why-add-block-level-to-pseudo-element/23399736#23399736) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to accomplish is to create an overlay that extends to the bottom of the page, try changing the position property to fixed and set the height to 100%.

```
#container {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    /* other CSS properties */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting height:100% to the body as well. Or you can use inherit feature,so it varies with the html height.

```
html
{
  min-height: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

body{
 margin:0px; 
 padding:0px;
 height:inherit;
} 

#container{
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height:inherit;
  border:1px solid #333;
 }
```

Please check in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rw99a/